# Class ClientBuilder(Neoxygen) not found in PHP

Tags: php, neo4j, neoxygen

Im trying to use Neoxygen in my PHP project. but im getting this error:

```
Class 'Neoxygen\NeoClient\ClientBuilder' not found in /var/www/html/work/api/vendor/myproj/myproj-core/src/MyProj/DatabaseTest/ManagersTest/AdminDbManagerTest.php.
```

my code :

```
<?php
namespace MyProj\DatabaseTest\ManagersTest;
use myProjCore\Tasks\AbstractClasses\ApiTask;
use Neoxygen\NeoClient\ClientBuilder;

class AdminDbManagerTest extends ApiTask
{
    /**
     * Start the running of the task
     */
    public function start()
    {
        $this->testDB();
    }


    private function testDB()
    {
        $client = ClientBuilder::create()
            ->addConnection('default','http','localhost',7474)
            ->build();
    }

}
```

I can reach the class by pressing the `ClientBuilder` (on testDB function) So I guess that the class is recognizes the ClientBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I pushed the files into my Git and pull them back and now it works. I think that the problem was in the composer update that I did.